# How to fix a node on its side parent group holder in cola.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, webcola

So Cola.JS [is beautiful](https://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/examples/dotpowergraph.html) but I wonder how to have a node that (via some attribute for example) stick to right side of its parent group holder?

Like nodes 26 27 28 here (a picture of what I would like to have):
[image]

Comment: Can you explain bit more so it may give clear idea

Comment: @DuckQueen, Can you explain a bit more so we can understand clearly?
What do you want from this question?

Comment: Have a subgraph group that would look more like a visual programming node with inputs and outputs